# convert to 3-digit hex color code

Tags: php, css, colors, hex

I've been using 3-digit hex color values in CSS for a long time: `#fff`, `#999`, `#069`, etc. I can see how the repeating letters/numbers are merged to create a 3-digit hex color code, but I don't fully understand the pattern to be able to write a converter in PHP. Is there documentation for this?

**Edit:** Oh, perhaps my question wasn't clear. I need to know how some of the 6-digit hex color values are converted to 3-digits. `xxxxxx` (`ffffff`) and `xxyyzz` (`006699`) – these are the only two patterns, correct?

Comment: Which way are you looking at converting? From 3 to 6-digit? Or from hex to decimal?

Comment: The benefits of a converter would surely be very limited. After all, only a small proportion of color codes can be simplified, and for a saving of only 3 characters per code. I'd be surprised if there's any documentation, but as a programming exercise, it's probably useful.

Comment: Oh, perhaps my question wasn't clear. I need to know how some of the 6 digit hex color values are converted to 3-digits? xxxxxx (ffffff) xxyyzz (006699), these are the only two patterns, correct?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To convert a 3-character hex code into a 6 character one, you need to repeat each character:

```
$hex = '#fff';
$hex6 = '#' . $hex[1] . $hex[1] . $hex[2] . $hex[2] . $hex[3] . $hex[3];
```

If you want to convert it to decimal you can use the [`hexdec`](http://php.net/hexdec) function

Answer (score 4):

3 digit CSS code is short for 6 digits": #06a; is #0066aa;
Each two digits represent a number from 0 to 255.
Converting these values to hex and back is all you need.

Answer (score 3):

`#f0f` is expanded to `#ff00ff` so basically you just need to calculate the value and the value times 16 for each character, e.g.:

`#f98`: f = 15 => red = 15 + 15*16 = 255 etc.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have missed the point - and my sense of consulting the API (`hexdec()`).

Comment: So, using this logic, you can just reverse it by dividing by 16 in order to get the hex 3 version?

Comment: @Josh Well, yes. But you'll effectively restrict yourself to a granularity of 16 per channel instead of 256.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function hexfix(str) {
  var v, w;
  v = parseInt(str, 16); // in rrggbb
  if (str.length == 3) {
    // nybble colors - fix to hex colors
 //  0x00000rgb              -> 0x000r0g0b
 //  0x000r0g0b | 0x00r0g0b0 -> 0x00rrggbb
 w = ((v & 0xF00) << 8) | ((v & 0x0F0) << 4) | (v & 0x00F);
 v = w | (w << 4);
  }
  return v.toString(16).toUpperCase();
 }

var hex1 = 'AABBCC',
    hex2 = 'ABC';

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hex1+" becomes "+hexfix(hex1)+'.  '));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hex2+" becomes "+hexfix(hex2)+'.  '));
```

Something like this.