# How to convert 3-digit HTML hex colors to 6-digit flex hex colors

Tags: apache-flex, colors, hex

I want to convert a 3-digit hex color which is coming from HTML CSS to a 6-digit hex color for Flex. Can anyone give me code to convert 3-digit hex colors to their 6-digit equivalents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert to 3-digit hex color code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459273/convert-to-3-digit-hex-color-code)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The three digit hex colors are expanded by doubling each digit (see [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-color-20010305#colorunits)).
So `#F3A` gets expanded to `#FF33AA`.

Answer (score 11):

Double every digit: for example `#A21` is equal to `#AA2211`.

However this question is a duplicate of: [convert to 3-digit hex color code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459273/3-digit-hex-color-code)

Answer (score 9):

Other answers provided the process but I will provide the code using regex and the java programming language

```
String value = "#FFF";
value = value.replaceAll("#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])", "#$1$1$2$2$3$3");
```

Comment: Thanks worked for Android/Java

Comment: Thanks, worked in vscode regexp find replace as well

Answer (score 1):

If you came here and is using Python, here's how:

```py
hex_code = '#FFF'
new_hex_code = '#{}'.format(''.join(2 * c for c in hex_code.lstrip('#')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version of Ovokerie's answer:

```kotlin
shortHexString.replace(Regex("#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])"), "#$1$1$2$2$3$3")
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP Version:

```
  /**
 * returns a clean 6 digit hex number as a string
 * @param $hex
 * @return false|string
 */
function clean_hex_color($hex)
{
    $hex = strtolower($hex);
    //remove the leading "#"
    if (strlen($hex) == 7 || strlen($hex) == 4)
        $hex = substr($hex, -(strlen($hex) - 1));

    // $hex like "1a7"
    if (preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{6}$/i', $hex))
        return $hex;
    // $hex like "162a7b"
    elseif (preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{3}$/i', $hex))
        return $hex[0] . $hex[0] . $hex[1] . $hex[1] . $hex[2] . $hex[2];
    //any other format
    else
        return "000000";
}
```