# Color.parseColor is throwing an error and app crashed

Tags: java, android, crash

I am having following list of colors to parse.

```
#FCA016
#315FBB 
#DC4926
#000 // This color not parsing
```

Throwing below exception

```
 09-15 01:10:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2379): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
 09-15 01:10:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):    at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:216)
```

Comment: the html color codes must be of 6 characters superscript by # tag,for your black color the it should be #000000

Comment: why don't you use `Color.parse("#000000");`?

Answer (score 3):

Three digit colour strings are not supported by `Color.parseColor()` - see the [API documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29).

> Supported formats are:
>    #RRGGBB
>    #AARRGGBB

You will need to convert your colour string to the correct format, see [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230331/how-to-convert-3-digit-html-hex-color-to-6-digit-flex-hex-color) for guidance.

Answer (score -2):

```
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```