# Css colors (#999 for example) - Why just three digits?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [3 digit Hex color code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459273/3-digit-hex-color-code)
>   [Using 3-digit color codes rather than 6-digit color codes in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108860/using-3-digit-color-codes-rather-than-6-digit-color-codes-in-css)

I have a color that has the following RGB values:

```
255-223-145
```

I see that lots of pages have the colors with just three digits, for example:

```
color: #999;
```

I wonder why, and how would I convert these rgb values to a three digit color.

Thanks

Comment: RGB to Hex - http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm

Comment: The calculator that comes standard with Windows can convert between decimal <-> hex.  View > Programmer: set it to `Dec` when you want to see/type in decimal numbers, set it to `Hex` when you want to see/type hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't a three digit colour, #999 is merely shorthand for #999999 so unless your numbers repeat like #223322 (#232) you can't cut it down.

The question has two bits, to convert hex to rgb, use a tool like [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) or [this](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/) online.

Answer (score 4):

`#999` is shorthand for `#999999`, and `#ABC` is short for `#AABBCC`. CSS colors can be shortened if you don't need the full six hex digits.

Your color in hex is `#FFDF91`. The closest three-digit color would be `#FD8` (`#FFDD88`). Close, though not identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can write shortly if you have 2 same digits

```
FF -> F
99 -> 9
```

So #999 = #999999 and #FFF = #FFFFFF